# How do I pass a context to a non Activity?

Tags: java, android

I keep getting a null pointer exception whenever I try to pass my context as a parameter to a non activity. Is there a way to properly pass a context through when I need to call functions from a non activity? Hope I can get some help with this. This is my code.

In Functions.java (Not an activity)

```
public String checkConnection(Context context){
        Context inContext = context;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("CheckConnection",response.substring(0,100));
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        Volley.newRequestQueue(inContext).add(stringRequest);
        return null;
    }
```

In Home.java (Activity)

```
Functions functions;
functions.checkConnection(Home.this);
```

Hope someone can help

Comment: use Singleton Volley in application lifecycle

Comment: Where in your Activity is that code? Is it inside a function?

Comment: you probably forgot to initialize `Functions` as `Functions functions = new Functions()` then use `functions.checkConnection(Home.this);`

Comment: The Function declaration is outside any functions. functions.check Connection is in a function called initialize()

Comment: Firstly, `functions` needs to be instanced (at the moment it is only declared). Other than that, I don't understand your problem. Is your App crashing?

Comment: Thanks guys! So sorry I didn't realize I forgot that functions wasn't instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Functions functions = new Functions();
functions.checkConnection(Home.this);
```